# The method onBackPressed() of type FirstGroup must override a superclass method

Tags: java, android, overriding

I'm trying to override the `onBackPressed()` method of the `ActivityGroup` class:

```
public class MyClass extends ActivityGroup {

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // do something
        return;
    }
```

but I'm getting the error `The method onBackPressed() of type MyClass must override a superclass method`.

I'm relatively new to Java, I've [seen here that people do it](http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/) and it works for them

Why I'm getting this error?

I'm writing an app for android 1.5, could the problem be here?

Comment: Burjua, please remove last line in u post.. i missed post and corrected wrong post :( Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

You need to override the back button like this

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "back button pressed");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Yes u r correct `onBackPressed()` method has been introduced only in API Level 5 which means you can use it only from 2.0 SDK

---

Comment: Adding super.onBackPressed() won't help if the method isn't defined in the superclass. You *could* remove the @Override annotation, in which case this would build against 1.5, but the onBackPressed method wouldn't be called.