# overriding OnbackPressed() method

Tags: android

[The method onBackPressed() of type FirstGroup must override a superclass method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658301/the-method-onbackpressed-of-type-firstgroup-must-override-a-superclass-method)

there's a problem just like the link above except for that my API lvl is 10 and if i'm right there should be already available a way to override onBackPress(); ?

P.S. my activity extends Fragment activity of support.v4 library

```
public class DetailsActivity extends FragmentActivity {



    @Override
    public void OnBackPressed()
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right,R.anim.hold );

    }
```

Comment: This should be doable for sure. Can you post a code sample of what you have been trying to run?

Comment: In your provided link, he is extending ActivityGroup, which has no onBackPressed method, so its normally that Java Compiler told him that there is no superclass method to override with that name. If you are overriding FragmentActivity, there has to be no problem overriding onBackPressed

Comment: Check my response, your first chat must be 'o', not 'O'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing `OnBackPressed` with the first letter capitalized. Its `onBackPressed`

Comment: ahahahahahaha....i'm a complete moron))))) thanks, dude) That's a sign for me to have a break) 

oh, yeah, btw it works fine now)

Comment: You are not a moron, its a normal mistake, in fact IntelliSense does most part of this kind of job :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                  // do what ever you want
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onBackPressed%28%29), you should be able to do it. Just add the method like this and you should be fine:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    //Your logic here
}
```

Comment: but still i can't..( i've posted my code above

Answer (score 0):

you could try this if `onBackPressed` does not work:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0){
    //code here
}
```

Comment: I have already answered same :) see below :D

Comment: @bobby.dhillon I was busy answering ... didn't see that :B